# Audio not work via /etc/init.d/xdm

Tags: linux, audio, dwm

gentoo linux 3.10.17
Display Manager: lightdm 1.9.5
Window Manager : dwm

```
# file: /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
session-wrapper=/etc/lightdm/Xsession
autologin-user=jeremy
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

The problem is if I start dwm using `startx`, the audio works fine.
But if I start it using `/etc/init.d/xdm start`, the audio can't work properly. Only noise I'll get.

And if I've invoked `startx` then quit and restart using `/etc/init.d/xdm start`, the audio works fine, too!

I'm quite confused about these two different ways to start dwm. What cause the difference?

**UPDATE**: Now I believe it's because this line:

```
# file: /etc/X11/Sessions/dwm == ~/.xinitrc
# ... some settings
exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session /usr/bin/dwm
```

which enable the ConsoleKit support for dwm. And I'm not sure would this command works for lightdm. Or lightdm uses another entry to start dwm?

Seems it's a [bug](https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=479660) supposed to be fixed at version 1.7.16...